# openNLPmodels.en error while trying to extract entity in text analysis

Tags: opennlp

I am using R3.1.2 for text analysis to extract entity(kind=person). i have loaded openNLP and openNLPmodels.en from http://datacube.wu.ac.at. but i get the following error.

Error in Maxent_Simple_Entity_Detector(language, kind, probs, model) : 
  Could not find model file for language 'en' and kind 'person'.
Apparently, package 'openNLPmodels.en' is installed
but does not provide this model.

What is the resolution?

Thanks
Sridevi

Comment: try downloading en-ner-person.bin from here http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/

Answer (score 3):

Let me provide the exact steps that worked for me. These steps assume you already have have OpenNLP, rJava libraries working.

1. **Install openNLPmodels.en**

`install.packages("openNLPmodels.en", dependencies=TRUE, repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/")`

2. **Navigate to the openNLPmodels.en library folder**. For me, this was  \filesrv\users\MYNAME\My Documents\R\win-library\3.4\openNLPmodels.en
3. Create a new folder within openNLPmodels.en called models

[image: models folder creation]

4. **Visit the openNLP models page on [sourceforge](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) and download 
   two files: en-chunker.bin and en-ner-person.bin**
5. **Place those files in your models folder**.

Comment: Thanks. First step solved it for me. It created the folder in the right place automatically. No need to download files from source forge. Following [this tutorial](https://slcladal.github.io/tagging.html#POS-Tagging_a_German_text) for POS-tagging in German but it did not download the language model

Answer (score 1):

Install the openNLPmodels.en from http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/. This package is no more available on CRAN. So, download is offline and install it on your R/Rstudio. It is working for me. ! Hurray !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it installing the additional packages "RWeka" and "qdap". Additionally, ensure you have 'rJava' installed. In short, run the following and see if, after requiring the packages, you are able to run your code.

```
install.packages(c("NLP", "openNLP", "RWeka", "qdap", "rJava"))
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have probably installed openNLPmodels.en and its loading properly. I went into the source code of parse.R of openNLP and found something like this

```
package <- "openNLPmodels.en"
model <- system.file("models/en-parser-chunking.bin",
                     package = package) .
```

## Points to be noted ..

1) I am on a Linux machine with R version of 3.3.2. and 
2) have installed version of openNLPmodels.en form 
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/openNLPmodels.en/ . to my surprise i didn't find "models/en-parser-chunking.bin" in its path.so i have downloaded the corresponding parser file. from http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/ and placed it in the folder called models. and  was able to get it working.

```
parse_annotator <- Parse_Annotator()
## Compute the parse annotations only.
p <- parse_annotator(s, a2)
```

now this code worked for me.
Prior to this i as having similar error with.

```
annotate(s, Maxent_Chunk_Annotator(), a3)
#Error in Maxent_Simple_Chunker(language, probs, model) : 
Could not find model file for language 'en'.
```

Apparently, package 'openNLPmodels.en' is installed
Now Guess what, i have given the path to model (chunker.bin file) in Maxent_Simple_Chunker and was able to get it work.

## apologize for my poor formatting skills

#### all the parse and chunker code i used can be found in the documentation.if you want to reproduce the examples